# How can I get how many different 'values' are in a dataset for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
df['value'].value_counts()
```

This code gives me two columns. On the left I get the unique values in this column (say 15) and the right gives the frequencies of each (ranging from 1 to 100). However, I want the int count of the unique values on the left of 15. Can't figure this out. Thanks

Comment: `df['value'].nunique()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the number of unique values. Here are a few ways to go about it. Since I'm using `range(10)` to populate my sample DataFrame, all the methods below result in a value of `10` as we'd expect.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': random.choices(range(10), k=1000)})
```

Inspect the [`shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) of the DataFrame. The shape parameter will give you a tuple of (rows, columns) in your DataFrame.

```py
df.value_counts().shape[0]
```

When you call `len()` on a DataFrame, it returns the number of rows.

```py
len(df.value_counts())
```

Count the number of unique values in the DataFrame. [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

```py
len(df['value'].unique())
```

Probably the best way to do it. [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html)

```py
df.value.nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `reset_index()` at the end of the code, and save it to a DataFrame, then change the columns and rename the index column. Something like this:

```
temp_df = df['value'].value_counts().reset_index()
temp_df ['index'], temp_df ['value'] = temp_df ['value'], temp_df ['index']
temp_df.columns = ['count', 'value']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it right, but if you want to sum the the values of the left column that appear only once you could `df.groupby('values').filter(lambda x: len(x)==1)['values'].unique()`. Probably there is a better way, but that should do it.